Blazor Web + Azure AD B2C in .NET 9
I'm starting up a new project, and am having some design challenges.
Initial thoughts:

Blazor Web, mostly server to start, but more WASM over time as things grow and scalability becomes necessary.
Authenticate against Azure AD B2C tenant
.NET 9.

It seems Microsoft.Identity.Web is the way to go, but I can't seem to find a good example of how to integrate it with a mixed mode Blazor app. I.e. the user logs in once, and both the Server and WASM sides work. I'd think a JWT token would be sufficient to share between the two sides, but it's been more than a handful of years since I've been involved in security design decisions.
I'm trying to stay within the MS ecosystem, though I'm frustrated by the documentation. It's certainly plentiful, but their revisioning system obfuscates the history, so it's challenging to quickly tell what's written in the .NET 5 days, vs what's .NET 8+ for example (and this confuses the hell out of chatGPT, which keeps trying to get me to make a _Host.cshtml for my Blazor on .NET 9 app).
For the record, I have tried a number of the samples out there, and basically every tutorial I can find over the past week. They work in the Blazor .NET 5 / .NET 6 realm on the server side, but end up in weird redirect loops and other problems when I apply the same to Blazor on .NET 9.
I'm left both frustrated, and baffled that MS hasn't made this a 3 click wizard thing. Blazor + Azure AD B2C should be one of their default demo environments. The existing wizard only works on Server only v6, and "Microsoft Identity Platform" isn't an option for "Authentication Type" in the Blazor / .NET 9 Web new project wizard.
Any thoughts on where to head? Thanks in advance.

What is the error you are getting?

Right now, It logs in on the server side, but logout triggers an infinite redirect loop.  context.User.Identity.Name isn't populated.  And when I try to login via google, it throws a javascript error in code which isn't mine.  Altogether I don't think my current code is architecturally right, so I'm trying to step back and ask for direction at the higher level first.. i.e. what's the "right modern way" to do what I'm trying to do, and is there a sample out there I should start from?

Also, I'm not sure what pages are coming from where..  e.g. "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn" and "signin-oidc"  There's a lot of magic behind the scenes, which is great when things work perfectly, but doesn't seem to be so perfect when pointed at Azure B2C..

@Peter Drier Which option is selected for the interactive render mode: server or webassembly?

@AsleshaKantamsetti "Both"..  it depends on which page for which mode it's using.  Thus a bit of the challenge here, how to make it so both the server and webassembly sides work.

I followed this document and created Sample Blazor Web app with Server render using .net9 and configured authentication with Azure AD B2C.
Below is my complete program.cs code.
Program.cs:
using BlazorApp3.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
namespace BlazorApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            var env = builder.Environment;
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true);
            builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
            builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
                        {

                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            ctxt.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(ctxt.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                            ctxt.HandleResponse();
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnTicketReceived = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            if (ctxt.Principal != null)
                            {
                                if (ctxt.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                                {
                                    var colClaims = await ctxt.Principal.Claims.ToDynamicListAsync();
                                    var IdentityProvider = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider")?.Value;
                                    var Objectidentifier = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
                                    var EmailAddress = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")?.Value;
                                    var FirstName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")?.Value;
                                    var LastName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname")?.Value;
                                    var AzureB2CFlow = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference")?.Value;
                                    var auth_time = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "auth_time")?.Value;
                                    var DisplayName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
                                    var idp_access_token = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "idp_access_token")?.Value;
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                    };
                });
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            var app = builder.Build();
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.UseAntiforgery();
            app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
                .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

I added below values to the appsetting.json:
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
  "ClientId": "{ClientId}",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "Domain": "{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "{Signup policy}",
  "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "",
  "EditProfilePolicyId": ""
},  

I added the below code to MainLayout.razor.
MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    Hello @context.User.Identity?.Name!
                    <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <a href="/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Sign in with your social account</a>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

I added below line to _Imports.razor:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

Make sure Add the redirect URl https://localhost:7293/signin-oidc in Authentication section of Azure App registration.

Output:




This answer helps in it's completeness on the server side, but doesn't address the webassembly/client side of things from what I can tell.  How is one to handle that side of user interaction / api auth without requiring the user to log in twice?

@Peter Drier For webassembly refer this doc.
